# creating an incremented label based on a logical test in R

Tags: r

Say I have a vector in a data frame, `data`, of 0's and 1's, like this:

```
v1<- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0)
```

I want a new vector, whose values are a or b, based on whether the value in `v1` is 0 or 1. Furthermore, I want the first a to be a1, the second to be a2. I want the first b to be b1, the second to be b2, etc. The output vector, `v2`, would look like

```
c(a1,a2,b1,b2,a3,b3,a4)
```

I know I can do a simple ifelse statement such that

```
data$v2 <- ifelse(data$v1=0,'a','b')
```

however, I don't know how to add an incrementing integer in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility:

```
paste0(letters[v1 + 1], ave(v1, v1, FUN = seq_along))
#   [1] "a1" "a2" "b1" "b2" "a3" "b3" "a4"
```

Instead of `letters` you may use `c("a", "b")`. But, `letters` = 7 keystrokes vs `c("a", "b")` = 11 keystrokes and 6 `shift`.

Comment: I was about to post a much less elegant answer. Thank you for saving me the embarrassment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I modify this if I wanted the text labels to be more complex? for instance, cat1, cat2, dog1, dog2?